# Matlab: error in "horzcat" when using matlabFunction to generate file from symbolic expessions

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, robotics

**This question contains a lot of code, but a lot of it is error messages and parameter definitions.**

I am trying to generate a matlab function script to calculate the dynamics of a 4-link robot manipulator. The goal is to make the function take a bunch of parameters(vectors/matrices) as inputs and return system matrices D, C and G. All calculations are done symbolically according to standard formulas found in any robotics textbook. I have looked through all my calculations and find no errors here.

When the calculations are complete, the function file is generated by the following line of code:

```
  matlabFunction(D,C,G,'File','getDynamicsFnc','Vars',{[q], [q_dot], [I1], [I2], [I3], [I4], 
  [th_a], [DH_params], [m], [com], [g]});
```

This leads to the following error message:

```
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in sym/matlabFunction>computeVarnames (line 902)
    allNames = matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings([repelem("ft",1,nuOfBlocks-1), "ft" 
        allVars],1:nuOfBlocks-1,namelengthmax);

Error in sym/matlabFunction>postProcessing (line 826)
        [newFunctionNames, newArgumentName] = computeVarnames(blocks);

Error in sym/matlabFunction (line 198)
    blocks = postProcessing(blocks);

Error in generate_func_complete (line 119)
    matlabFunction(D,C,G,'File','getDynamicsFnc','Vars',{[q], [q_dot], [I1], [I2], [I3], [I4], 
        [th_a], [DH_params], [m], [com], [g]});
```

I have checked the dimensions of all elements in the workspace and find no inconsistencies. I tried running the script with dummy-values for D, C and G and it worked properly (even when they were made up of elements from the transformation/Jacobi matricies that are calculated in the script).

The following code shows how D, C and G are calculated:

```
D = sym(zeros(dim)); C = sym(zeros(dim)); G = sym(zeros(dim,1));

% D matrix
for i = 1:dim                                         % T{i} is a 4X4 matrix that was calculated previously
    R = T{i}(1:3,1:3);
    It = simplify(R*I{i}*R');
    D = D + m(i)*J_v{i}'*J_v{i} + J_w{i}'*It*J_w{i};  % Calculate D
    P = P + m(i)*gvec'*rc{i};                         % Potential energy. Used to find G later
end
P = simplify(P);

% C matrix
for i= 1:dim
    for j=1:dim
        for k=1:dim
            christ = 0.5*(diff(D(i,j),q(k)) + diff(D(i,k),q(j)) - diff(D(k,j),q(i))); % Calculating Christoffel symbols
            C(i,j) = C(i,j) + christ*q_dot(k);                                        % Summing Christoffel symbols to find elements of C
        end        
    end
end

% G matrix
for i = 1:dim
    G(i) = diff(P,q(i));                              % Calculating G
end
```

I will not include calculations for T, J or rc due to the length of the code, but I have already verified that they are not the problem. All other parameters used are defined as follows:

```
dim   = 4;
q     = sym('q',[dim 1],'real');
q_dot = sym('q_dot',[dim 1],'real');

I1 = sym('I1', [3 3],'real');
I2 = sym('I2', [3 3],'real');
I3 = sym('I3', [3 3],'real');
I4 = sym('I4', [3 3],'real');
I  = cell(1,4);
I{1} = I1; I{2} = I2; I{3} = I3; I{4} = I4;

th_a      = sym('th_a','real');
DH_params = sym('DH_params', [5 4],'real');
com       = sym('com', [5 3],'real');
m         = sym('m', [1 dim],'real');
g         = sym('g','real');
gvec      = [0;0;g];
```

NOTE: I do not use the simplify function when calculating the outputs. This is due to the extreme increase in runtime for the script, to the point where it won't finnish over several hours.

I included a lot of code in this question, but I believe it is fairly simple to understand and hopefully not too exessive. Please give feedback if I overdid it.

Comment: This is unrelated to your error, but when you do `[q]` you are concatenating `q` with noting. It is the same as just writing `q`, except it's slower.

Comment: Regarding your error, I would suggest to turn on the debugger and try to figure out where inside the `matlabFunction` function this is happening. This should give you some insight into what the problem is. It is likely that it is trying  to concatenate `D`, `C` and `G` along the first dimension, which wouldn't work because `G` has only one column.